# jquery loading script when preparing document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jquery and would appreciate a help from stackoverflow community to solve following problem

Lets assume that there a server side script which creates doc file and following links calls it

`<a class="prepare_doc_file" href="somepage.php?action=docfile">docfile</a>`

what i need is jquery script, which shows loading image, when doc file if being prepared (or when the link is clicked) and hide it after getting download popup.

I see loading circle in the tab in browser. I need the same thing inside the html document

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use AJAX, and generate a tempfile to download.
Your php can generate file and save to some temp path. After downloading you can delete this file.

```
<a class="prepare_doc_file" id="downloadfile" href="somepage.php?action=docfile">docfile</a>
function loadFile(){
document.getElementById('downloadfile').innerHTML='loading, please wait';
$.ajax({
        url: 'somepage.php?action=docfile',
        complete: function (data) {
             document.getElementById('downloadfile').href='path to file'; //path may be returned on php.
             document.getElementById('downloadfile').innerHTML='docfile';
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myDiv">
<img src="loading gif image url">
</div>
<script>
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url to the page where the contnt is",
            data: 'parameters if any' ,
            success: function(result){
               //logics
                $("#myDiv").html("<a class="prepare_doc_file" href="somepage.php?action=docfile">docfile</a>");

            });
</script>
```